# Php in HTML doesn't work

Tags: php, html

Look, i have html with included php link but that doesn't work well.Information what was in html doesn't come to php page. Please help with that.

**HTML** CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
➝ XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/
➝ DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/
➝ 1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
➝ lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
➝ content="text/html;
➝ charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Greetings!</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Script 3.6 - hello.html -->
<div><p>Click a link to say
➝ hello:</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="hello.php?
name=Michael">Michael</a></li>
<li><a href="hello.php?
name=Celia">Celia</a></li>
<li><a href="hello.php?
name=Jude">Jude</a></li>
<li><a href="hello.php?
name=Sophie">Sophie</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
➝ XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/
➝ DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/
➝ 1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
➝ lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
➝ content="text/html;
➝ charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Greetings!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php // Script 3.7 - hello.php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$name - $_GET['name'];
print "<p>Hello, <span
style=\font-weight:
bold;\">$name</span>!</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this how it's look on web 
http://santa-monica.comli.com/hello.html

http://santa-monica.comli.com/hello.php?name=Michael

Comment: you have error in `print`. Try this: `print "<p>Hello, <span style='font-weight:bold;'>".$name."</span>!</p>";`

Comment: i think you missed the "=" sign in the code  ..  `$name = $_GET["name"]`

Comment: You even have error-reporting on, it will tell you what's wrong. I can spot at least one mistake: `$name - $_GET['name'];` does not set the variable. It should be `$name = $_GET['name'];` (still could produce *Undefined index*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link to the php page is working fine, your problem is where u define the name variable, you have a typo, instead of `$name = $_GET['name'];` you put `$name - $_GET['name'];`, dont worry this happens to the best of us, fix that and it should run smoothly, btw if you are testing your php code on an online server dont, because it is slower than on your pc, unless you are contacting an api, it doesnt work unless its executing online

EDIT :

change your code to this :

```
<?php // Script 3.7 - hello.php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$name = $_GET['name'];
?>
<p>Hello, <span
style=\font-weight:
bold;\"><?php echo $name; ?></span>!</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

change your php code to this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
➝ XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/
➝ DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/
➝ 1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
➝ lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
➝ content="text/html;
➝ charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Greetings!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php // Script 3.7 - hello.php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$name = $_GET['name'];
print '<p>Hello, <span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$name.'</span>!</p>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```